# Does Grafana permanently store Postgres Datasource metrics?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, grafana

I've been looking through the docs and grafana community but can't seem to find a definitive answer to this.

I have Grafana configured witha  PostgreSQL datasource and created a dashboard to monitor the number of new sessions being created in my database. This works, and I can see a graph of sessions being generated over time.

My question is regarding where the numbers are recorded, if anywhere? If I have this graph on my dashboard, does it go away and make the query every single time the page is loaded? My main concern is that a user can change the time period, going back potentially years, which would hammer the database grouping all those sessions into time intervals.

If they are not stored anywhere with Grafana, how are people managing this? Would we need to use another 'middle man' to receive all of the stats, and use this as the datasource instead of the PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

When you configured the datasource, you are telling grafana to pick data from there. In your case it is your postgres db.

Grafana does not copy data anywhere else.

If you want that then you should store that data somewhere else. You can setup monitoring for postgresql and store metrics in some engines like prometheus.